# unable to fetch full data inside<div>

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

HTML:

```
<div>
    Está en: <b>     
            <a href="/">Inicio</a> /       
            <a href="/proyectos-vivienda-nueva/valle-del-cauca/">Valle Del Cauca</a> /            
            <a href="/proyectos-vivienda-nueva/cali/">Cali</a> /                         
            <a href="/proyectos-vivienda-nueva/sur/cali/">Zona Sur</a> /                       
            <a href="/proyectos-vivienda-nueva/zona-sur/cali/">Zona Sur</a> /                         
    <a>Los Naranjos Conjunto Campestre</a></b>
</div>
```

Unable to fetch all `<a>` tags inside `<div>` tag

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/oceana-52/barranquilla/proyecto-nuevo-det-1041165.aspx')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
first = soup.find('div' , 'breadcrumb left')
link = first.find('div')
a_link = link.findAll('a')
print (a_link)
```

The above coding only printing the first `<a>` tag

```
[<a href="/">Inicio</a>]
```

Following are the output required from the above HTML

```
Valle Del Cauca 
Cali 
Zona Sur 
Zona Sur
```

I'm not sure why it was not printing after `'/'` inside `<b>` tag

Comment: Did you try with different parser?

Answer (score 1):

You can use lxml parser, html.parser normalizes/prettify the actual source before BS4 parse it.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
```

Comment: Great! Please don't forget to tag this as answer. Thanks!